# Opencart Remove \65279” from HTML

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Inside my `home.tpl`, I deleted everything. But when I go to `/index.php?route=common/home`, it shows like this at the top:
[image: screenshot of source code]

I also tried to open `home.tpl` using Notepad++ and encoded it as "UTF-8 without BOM". For another page this is working fine.

Comment: Have you checked? 1. catalog/controller/home.php 2. Vqmod (if there) xml files related with home page

Comment: @Samir for home.php I have checked already.But what is Vqmod and where is it?